# Как сформулировать правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Великолепие и роскошь отображается в тонком дизайне этих ювелирных изделий. Носить украшение вашего бренда - значит быть королевой.

Comment: Вам бы сначала научиться грамотно вопрос формулировать.

Comment: «Формулировка грамотной речи и знаки препинания» — натужный выбух какой-то, как на Украине говорят. Исправлю.

Comment: А на кой ляд это править? Да еще с присказкой типа "А что там у хохлов?".

Answer (score 1):

Со знаками препинания здесь проблем нет. Грамматически предпочтительно множественное число глагола "отображаться", поскольку "великолепие" и "роскошь" - не совсем однородные понятия. Первое выражает преимущественно эстетическое впечатление (здесь это превосходная степень рукотворной красоты), второе констатирует видимую дороговизну, стоящую за наблюдаемыми красотами, и престижность обладания такими предметами. Однако сам глагол вряд ли удачно выбран: отображать - значит воспроизводить нечто реальное или воображаемое (идеи) в выбранной форме (здесь юв. изделия). Великолепие же и роскошь являются *прямыми свойствами* того, о чём говорят. Если и можно здесь говорить об "*отображении*", то лишь в смысле отображения эстетических взглядов ювелира в изделии, которое может в глазах потребителя выглядеть роскошным и великолепным. Поэтому глагол нужен другой; по смыслу можно было бы сказать "сквозят (видны)", но возможно, что найдётся и более удачный. Слово "бренд" (ярлык, товарный знак, торговая марка) стилистически плохо соседствует с эстетическими эпитетами. Если нужно сослаться на производителя, лучше сказать "вашей фирмы" или назвать её (либо серию её изделий) напрямую, напр. "Носить украшения от Fabergé...".

Answer (score 0):

В этих ювелирных изделиях великолепие и роскошь сочетаются  с изысканным и высокохудожественным дизайном. Носить **украшения** от_____ - значит быть королевой.

Для сравнения: стильный тонкий дизайн **(о планшете)**.